# How do packages work in golang

Tags: import, go, package

I was trying to understand how packages work in go better in terms of what golang actually enforces rather than what is usually done or considered good practice (we can talk about good practice later too, but I wish to understand go first).

From [effective go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#package-names) it says:

> "Another convention is that the package name is the base name of its source directory..."

However, the description above doesn't seem to be forced by go or required. Thus, I was wondering, if I was allowed to have **multiple** files with **different** package declarations at the top in the **same** directory base. If I am allowed to have multiple package declaration in the same directory, how do I then import them and use each one separately in the same file? Basically, I guess one of the problem I have is due to the wording of some of the go tutorial/documentation. If it is by convention, then for me, its implied that it is **NOT enforced by the language**. Because for example, go programmers do NOT write the keyword `func` for a function by convention. We write `func` because otherwise go will yell at you and it will **not compile**. Thus, I wish to clarify this with the example bellow (and if possible change the documentation for go, because this is a big deal in my opinion, how can this be done?).

For example say I have three file `A.go`, `B.go`, `C.go` that print a print function `Print()` that simply prints a,b,c respectively. They are all on the same base directory called maybe `base`. Then each has a different package declaration `package Apkg, package Bpkg, package Cpkg`.

how would you then go and import them? Would something as follow work?

```
package main

import(
    nameA "github.com/user_me/base/Apkg"
    nameB "github.com/user_me/base/Bpkg"
    nameC "github.com/user_me/base/Cpkg"
)

func main() {
    nameA.Print() \\prints a
    nameB.Print() \\prints b
    nameC.Print() \\prints c
}
```

or maybe we don't even need to specify the name if the package statments are the top are already different:

```
package main

import(
    "github.com/user_me/base"
)

func main() {
    Apkg.Print() \\prints a
    Bpkg.Print() \\prints b
    Cpkg.Print() \\prints c
}
```

the printing file are:

A.go:

```
//file at github.com.user_me/base and name A.go
package Apkg

import "fmt"

func Print(){
    fmt.Println("A")
}
```

B.go:

```
//file at github.com.user_me/base and name B.go
package Bpkg

import "fmt"

func Print(){
    fmt.Println("B")
}
```

C.go:
    //file at github.com.user_me/base and name C.go
    package Cpkg

```
import "fmt"

func Print(){
    fmt.Println("C")
}
```

Also, if you can have a name **different** from the `base`, could someone clarify to me how the import is actually done? If the package name is `package Apkg` in base does the import have to be `import github.com/user_me/base` or `import github.com/user_me/base/Apkg` or `github.com/user_me/Apkg`.

I have not yet tested this but I will do so soon. The importing deal in go has been a little confusing for me and would love to get an answer and share it with the world.

Answer (score 9):

No, it's 1 package per folder, so you would have to have them :

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/user_me/base/Apkg/a.go
$GOPATH/src/github.com/user_me/base/Bpkg/b.go
$GOPATH/src/github.com/user_me/base/Cpkg/c.go
```

You can't even build it otherwise:

```
┌─ oneofone@Oa [/t/blah]                                                                                                         
└──➜ go build
can't load package: package .: found packages pkgA (blah1.go) and pkgB (blah2.go) in /tmp/blah
```

Your your package name doesn't need to have the same name as the directory they are in, however all files in one directory must have the same package name.

Also, you can rename packages on import, for example:

```
import (
   cr "crypto/rand"
   mr "math/rand"
)
```

Or your library is called main (bad idea btw) :

```
import m "github.com/user_me/base/main"
```

Comment: Interesting that they phrase it in such a weird way by saying its "convention" if the language does enforce it. The reason I was skeptical and confused about this was because previously, I had a package name at the top of my files for `base` that did NOT match the base dir name. So for example, I had `package superBase` rather than `package base` and I was still able to run `go test` even though my import was `import baseName github.com/user_me/base` but the package for each file was 'package superBase'. Weird. Is this a special thing about `go test`?

Comment: your package name doesn't have to match the dir name BUT all the files in the dir have to have the same package name. You can also rename the package in your import, that way for example you can have `import (cr "crypto/rand"; mr "math/rand")`.

Comment: Alright. Also, do you mind writing that too in your answer to make all the info be in one place please? Thanks for the help btw, you didn't even give me a chance to test this on my own! I still will though just to be 100% sure and to practice some more with go :)

Comment: I added some extra info, please mark it as the answer if it's what you were asking for.

Comment: @CharlieParker strictly speaking the **language** doesn't enforce it, the **build tool** does. It's entirely possible to write a custom Makefile that compiles Go by directly calling the compiler/linker without the 1 package/per directory restriction. But `go build` is so integrated into Go that the language *may as well* enforce it.

Comment: @Jsor Thats a great comment! I was not aware you could do that (though now that I think about it, I can't think of a reason that you couldn't). Though, I have no idea how one would call the go compiler as its usually done for C files and stuff. Though, your answer at the end implies that the compiler *does* enforce, even if its because of the build tool...if the compiler enforces it on the newest realizes then its part of the language and thats it. Or am I wrong?

Comment: However, this doesn't seem completely exact, since (as ginkgo does) it is possible to have package "something" and package "something_test" in the same directory. They *are* treated as two separate packages, as you need to import "something" in the "something_test"-namespaced files. What is the logic then ?